# Installing RESTful services and Tomcat 8 with Oracle Apex on Linux

Tags: oracle, rest, tomcat, oracle-apex, rhel

I am playing around with Oracle Apex on a Linux RHEL 6 box, mainly as an enthusiastic amateur.

I am trying to install RESTful services and Tomcat 7 to allow me to print from Apex.

I have followed some good web based guides, but have found that Tomcat will not work as port 8080 is being used by 'Webcache'.

I've reached a bit of a dead end, mainly due to my novice status. Can anyone point me in the right direction of what Webcache is and how I might change the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easier to change the tomcat port rather than webcache.

- Stop the tomcat server
- Edit the server.xml ($tomcat_home$/conf) and change the port to something like 8088 or whatever free port you want to use
- Startup the tomcat server
- Open your web browser and verify connectivity by entering the URL to your tomcat server and new port (e.g. http://localhost:8088)